# pygame.surfarray.array2d returns artifacts from previous rendering

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I am trying to get the 2d array that represents what's on the display in pygame. However whenever i call the `pygame.display.update()` method and then  call the `pygame.surfarray.array2d` I get parts of the previous image in my array.

This happens even if i allow certain amount of time to pass before I fetch the array.

The actual display of the game does not contain those artifacts and it displays correctly.

All I am doing is 
1. updating the coordinates of the  sprites 
2. call the `pygame.display.update()` and wait for user input
3. calling `pygame.surfarray.array2d(self.display)`to get the screen as an array
where `self.display = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))` 
I did try on pygame.display.get_surface() instead and it made no difference

Here is the example of how it looks:

[image]
[image]

Original game has no artifact:
[image]

Any ideas of what is going on here or how I can debug this??

Here is minimal verifiable example:

```
import pygame
import display_image as image_test

render_img = image_test.Render()

width = 400
height = 400
IMAGE_SIZE = 120

display = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
robot_image = pygame.image.load('robot_blue.png')
robot_image = pygame.transform.scale(robot_image, (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))
floor_image = pygame.image.load('floor.png')
floor_image = pygame.transform.scale(floor_image, (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))
def wait():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                return

x_position = 0
y_position = 0
display.blit(floor_image, (x_position, y_position))
display.blit(robot_image, (x_position, y_position))
pygame.display.update()
wait()
image = pygame.surfarray.array2d(display)
render_img(image, 400, 400)
x_position = 0
y_position = 120
display.blit(floor_image, (0, 0))
display.blit(robot_image, (x_position, y_position))
pygame.display.update()
wait()
image = pygame.surfarray.array2d(display)
render_img(image, 400, 400)
```

here is how i display_image:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot


class Render:
    def __init__(self, dpi=80.0, x_pixels=1040, y_pixels=780):
        self.dpi = dpi
        self.x_pixels, self.y_pixels = x_pixels, y_pixels

    def __call__(self, image, *args, **kwargs):
        plot.gray()
        if len(args) == 2:
            self.x_pixels = args[0]
            self.y_pixels = args[1]
        fig = plot.figure(figsize=(self.y_pixels / self.dpi, self.x_pixels / self.dpi), dpi=self.dpi)
        fig.figimage(image)
        plot.show()
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @skrx alright I posted an example

Comment: Using `self.display.fill((0, 0, 0))` before painting the images removes the artifacts however I am still not sure why the bug exists and I would like a better solution.

Comment: This seems to be a Pygame bug. Does it still occur with the latest Pygame version? If so then you should report it. You can create a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues).

Comment: @Rabbid76 I will try to test if i have time.  Since it is a very old question i will have to find the code on my old computer.

Comment: If the problem is no longer reproducible, you should write that in an answer or delete the question.